# Multiple random number results

Tags: java, android, random

Currently working in Android Studio and running into a little trouble. Trying to get my rollScore button to roll over and over. At this point it "rolls" once and stops. I've tried a for loop and while loop and unable to get it to allow multiple "rolls".

```
public class GameScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button rollButton; // Roll button being declared as a variable
    private TextView rollScore; // Text view being declared as a variable
    private TextView totalSCore; //
    private int mCounter = 0;
    private int totalRuns = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        final int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(7) + 1;

        rollButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
        rollScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollScore);
        totalSCore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalScore);



        rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    rollScore.setText(Integer.toString(randomInt));
                    mCounter++;

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate a new random number on each click on your button.

Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt;

    rollButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
    rollScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollScore);
    totalSCore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalScore);



    rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(7) + 1;
                rollScore.setText(Integer.toString(randomInt));
                mCounter++;

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a new random number after every roll e.g.

```
rollScore.setText(Integer.toString(randomGenerator.nextInt(7) + 1));
```